# abstract class in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have some code below

```
/*abstract*/ class Animal{
    protected $name;
    protected $legs;

    public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name; 
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    // abstract public function sound();
}


class Cat extends Animal{
    public function sound(){
        echo 'Meo meo meo';
    }
}

class Crocodile extends Animal{
    public function sound(){
        echo 'Never hear it';
    }
} 

function check(Animal $a){
    echo $a->getName();br();
    echo $a->sound();br();
}

$cat = new Cat();
$cat->setName("Cat");

$cro = new Crocodile();
$cro->setName('Nothing');


class test{
    public function check(Animal $a){
        echo $a->getName();
        echo $a->sound();
    }
}   


$t = new test();    
$t->check($cro);
```

I think, if don't use abstract so the last line $t->check($cro) must wrong, but Why it run nice.
I want ask a question, in class test with check method, $a->sound(); no exists in Animal but it still run. It run like when I open comment abstract class, both of thing is not different. I really wonder, maybe I have wrong understood this problem, twisted

Comment: Method `sound` exists in `Crocodile` class. That's why it runs.

Comment: but don't have in animal, and a parameter with Animal

Comment: You run check method on `Crocodile` class object. This object has `sound` method. Doesn't matter whether `Animal` has this method or not if method exists in child class.

Comment: So Why exists abstract in the world, while we use without it but still running. Like this, I can no define sound() in animal no problem

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php#82111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking about animals and specific animals, like cats and crocodiles. While in your definition the concept of animal is not related to the method of sound, specific animals, like cats and crocodiles, which are inherited from animals have the ability of sound. This is how you get from the more general to the more concrete. You will get more particularities at the end.

Your `Animal` `class` has a `protected` `$name` member along with a getter and a setter. They are useful, since you will not have to redefine these for `Crocodile` or `Cat`. But you could tell the `Animal` `class` that you do not know how the `sound` method will look like at particulars, but you do know that all `Animals` can make a `sound`. This is why the `class` is `abstract`: you can implement a part of it, but some things cannot be implemented at `Animal` level, as the different types of animals will have different types of sound.

Comment: @KIM, those are just names for functionalities which set or get values. For instance the setter of name is setName and the getter of name is getName